# Play framework 2.6 java websockets akka dependency injection

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, actor

I am using java websockets in play framework 2.6 and having hard time figuring out Guice DI. Below I am injecting DbService (which perform some db operations) but I am getting DbService as null and throwing NPE at line

```
User user = dbService.findByName(inEvent.getUsername());
```

dbService is null. I am not sure why its not injecting DbService. Although this work when I don't use it via akka actors. I do bind DbService to its implementation.

Actor

```
public class TestActor extends AbstractActor {
   @Inject
   private DbService dbService;

   private ActorRef out;

   public static Props props(final ActorRef out) {
      return Props.create(TestActor.class, out);
   }

   public TestActor(ActorRef out) {
       this.out = out;
   }

   @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
          .match(InEvent.class, inEvent -> {
              System.out.println(inEvent.getUsername());
              User user = dbService.findByName(inEvent.getUsername());
              System.out.println(user.getFirstName());
              out.tell("userName is ", self());
          }
            )
          .build();
    }

}
```

Controller

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public WebSocket TestWebSocket() {
        return WebSocket.json(InEvent.class).acceptOrResult(request -> {

            final Token token = verifyToken(request());
            if (token == null) {
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(F.Either.Left(forbidden()));
            }

            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
                    F.Either.Right(ActorFlow.actorRef(out -> TestActor.props(out), actorSystem, materializer)));

        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your actor will be constructed based on the parameters used in Props.create().

In your example:

```
Props.create(Class<TestActor>, ActorRef);
```

Will match the constructor in the **TestActor.class** with one argument of type **ActorRef**, and that constructor will be calle with the arguments that you provide.

You can change your constructor signature and the props method like this:

```
...
public static Prop props(ActorRef out, DBServide db) {
  return Props.create(TestActor.class, out, db);
}
...
public TestActor(ActorRef out, DBService db) {
  this.out = out;
  this.dbService = db;
}
...
```

With this, the constructor **TestActor(ActorRef, DBService)** will be used and you will get the instance of DBService used when you called the static method **props**.

Comment: This is just example, I have other services too which I want to inject. Isn't there any way not to pass it to constructor and directly inject in actor. Isn't there any guice magic we can do to inject directly this in actors

Comment: It is mandatory to do it with guice?. I couldn't do it, maybe someone did it.... With the current code, there is dependency injection. Every time a new connection to the WebSocket is made, an instance of the Actor is created with the information given.

Comment: I have to use guice for dependency injection.